# Attach metadata to the entities using JSON

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm using the new release of the contextbroker 0.13.0. In this new version is possible to attach metadata to the attributes of the entities. I can't find any example of how could attach this metadata using JSON. Could you show me an example?

The message could be somthing like it?

```
{
"contextElements": [
    {
        "type": "analyzer",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "metadata",
        "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "ae",
            "type": "kWh",
            "value": "4",
            "Metadata": {["name": "ts",
                               "type": "ms",
                               "value": "1401894337000"]}
        }
        ]
    }
],
"updateAction": "APPEND"
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following updateContext:

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "analyzer",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "metadata",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "ae",
                    "type": "kWh",
                    "value": "4",
                    "metadatas": [
                        {
                            "name": "ts",
                            "type": "ms",
                            "value": "1401894337000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

The right JSON field for metadata is `metadatas` (starting with lowercase and ending with 's').

A JSON example has been added in the [custom metadata section](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Custom_attribute_metadata)